# Cursor at the start of UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, viewcontroller

A ViewController consist of two TextFields named textName & textEmail. View Controller loads with cursor on textName. textName contain pre populated word "@gmail.com".

On hitting keyboard's return Key from textName, focus is moved to Textfield textEmail. Here by default, cursor is placed after the word "@gmail.com"

I would like to get the cursor placed at the start. i.e. before @gmail.com

Here is my code. When i hit return key from textName, cursor goes to the beginning of textEmail. But when I tap on textEmail directly, cursor appears after the pre populated word. Please help me!

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        if textField == self.textName{
            textEmail.becomeFirstResponder()
            let desiredPosition = textEmail.beginningOfDocument
            textEmail.selectedTextRange = textEmail.textRangeFromPosition(desiredPosition, toPosition: desiredPosition)
        }

        if textField == self.textEmail{


            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        }

        return true
    }
```

As a note, I did try editing did begin action for textEmail and added below  code but it didn't work either.

```
let desiredPosition = textEmail.beginningOfDocument
            textEmail.selectedTextRange = textEmail.textRangeFromPosition(desiredPosition, toPosition: desiredPosition)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == self.textName{
        let beginning = textField.beginningOfDocument
        textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: beginning, to: beginning)
    }
}
```

So remove `textEmail.becomeFirstResponder()` and use `textField.textRange` instead of `textEmail.textRangeFromPosition`.

And inside of the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` function use the parameter `textField` as shown in my example above.

Comment: i was using manually created DidBeginEditing action. textFieldDidBeginEditing worked.

Answer (score 0):

First tou set Delegate `UITextFieldDelegate`

After you TextField delegate set Self in viewDidLoad

**Example**

```
textName.delegate = self 
textEmail.delegate = self
```

then Copy this method in your viewController

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        if textField == textName
        {
            textName.resignFirstResponder()
            textEmail.becomeFirstResponder()
             textEmail.text = "@gmail.com"
            let newPosition = textField.beginningOfDocument
           textEmail.selectedTextRange = textEmail.textRangeFromPosition(newPosition, toPosition: newPosition)



        }
        else if textField == textEmail
        {
            textEmail.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }
```